# Compare number array with 'array of number arrays' to find matches

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I'm trying something I've never attempted before and I'm stumped on finding the solution (hopefully I'm not attempting the impossible!).

I have an array containing 24 individual arrays, each containing 4 number values each.

```
var arrayOfArrays = [
    [ 0, 7, 14, 21 ],
    [ 1, 8, 15, 22 ],
    [ 2, 9, 16, 23 ],
    [ 6, 13, 20, 27 ] and so on for 24 arrays.
```

I also have an empty array, which has a new number pushed into it on a click event. Each click adds a new number i.e.

```
var userGeneratedArray = []
- click
[7]
- click
[7, 32]
-click
[7, 32, 14]
-click
[7, 32, 14, 24]
-click
[7, 32, 14, 24, 34]
```

etc.

What I want to do is:

1) Every time a new number is added to userGeneratedArray, I want to loop through arrayOfArrays and compare numbers.

2) Once ANY four numbers in userGeneratedArray match ALL of the numbers in ANY of the arrays within arrayOfArrays, return true.

Any idea of how to construct this loop? Any help would be greatly appreciated :).

This is my full array of arrays

```
    var arrayOfArrays = [
        [ 0, 7, 14, 21 ],
        [ 1, 8, 15, 22 ],
        [ 2, 9, 16, 23 ],
        [ 6, 13, 20, 27 ],

        [ 7, 14, 21, 28 ],
        [ 8, 15, 22, 29 ],
        [ 12, 19, 26, 33 ],
        [ 14, 21, 28, 35 ],

        [ 18, 25, 32, 39 ],
        [ 19, 26, 33, 40 ],
        [ 20, 27, 34, 41 ],
        [ 36, 31, 26, 21 ],

        [ 37, 32, 27, 22 ],
        [ 38, 33, 28, 23 ],
        [ 30, 25, 20, 15 ],
        [ 31, 26, 21, 16 ],

        [ 32, 27, 22, 17 ],
        [ 24, 19, 13, 9 ],
        [ 25, 20, 15, 10 ],
        [ 26, 21, 16, 11 ],

        [ 18, 13, 8, 3 ],
        [ 19, 14, 9, 4 ],
        [ 20, 15, 10, 5 ],
        [ 13, 20, 27, 34 ]
    ];
```

Comment: You can use  `some` and `every` i.e. `arrayOfArrays.some(v=> v.every(u=> userGeneratedArray.includes(u)))`

Comment: Can there be duplicate numbers in `userGeneratedArray` and in any arrays of `arrayOfArrays` ?

Comment: Hi Cid, there will never be any duplicate numbers in ```userGeneratedArray```, and in ```arrayOfArrays``` the numbers are set in the combinations I've already listed in my post. Thanks :)

Comment: Looks like a game of bingo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the user to enter some array in the input and match with the arrays you've given completely and then return that array which is matched. This is very easy and can be done in steps

1. First, add a `keyup` to your input and when the user type, split the string into an array. There you have your array by the input
2. Then `forEach` over the `arrayOfArrays` to get every value inside.
3. Now `forEach` over the elements of `arrayOfArrays` and then do a `every` loop on the arrays. Check if every value matches the array if it does then return your answer

```js
var arrayOfArrays = [
  [0, 7, 14, 21],
  [1, 8, 15, 22],
  [2, 9, 16, 23],
  [6, 13, 20, 27],

  [7, 14, 21, 28],
  [8, 15, 22, 29],
  [12, 19, 26, 33],
  [14, 21, 28, 35],

  [18, 25, 32, 39],
  [19, 26, 33, 40],
  [20, 27, 34, 41],
  [36, 31, 26, 21],

  [37, 32, 27, 22],
  [38, 33, 28, 23],
  [30, 25, 20, 15],
  [31, 26, 21, 16],

  [32, 27, 22, 17],
  [24, 19, 13, 9],
  [25, 20, 15, 10],
  [26, 21, 16, 11],

  [18, 13, 8, 3],
  [19, 14, 9, 4],
  [20, 15, 10, 5],
  [13, 20, 27, 34]
];
let answer = []
document.querySelector("#val").onkeyup = function() {
  let array_user = this.value.split(',') // convert input  value to array 
  arrayOfArrays.forEach((array) => { // for every array inside arrayOfArrays
    let trues = array.every((val, index) => { // match every element inside the arrays of the variable arrayOfArrays and then return the condition
      return val == array_user[index]
    })
    if (trues){ // if your answer is correct then say yes
      console.log("ANSWER IS THIS => " +  array)
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<input id="val">
```

For instance, type `13, 20, 27, 34` in the input (or any other values from the array dictionary) and this will match the arrays inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a data structure that efficiently identifies the arrays in which a selected number occurs (avoiding to search them over and over again): a mapping of each selectable number to a list of array-objects that contain it. Add a counter to each such object to track whether all were selected.

Here is how that could look. I added buttons with which the numbers can be selected:

```js
const arrayOfArrays = [[ 0, 7, 14, 21 ],[ 1, 8, 15, 22 ],[ 2, 9, 16, 23 ],[ 6, 13, 20, 27 ],[ 7, 14, 21, 28 ],[ 8, 15, 22, 29 ],[ 12, 19, 26, 33 ],[ 14, 21, 28, 35 ],[ 18, 25, 32, 39 ],[ 19, 26, 33, 40 ],[ 20, 27, 34, 41 ],[ 36, 31, 26, 21 ],[ 37, 32, 27, 22 ],[ 38, 33, 28, 23 ],[ 30, 25, 20, 15 ],[ 31, 26, 21, 16 ],[ 32, 27, 22, 17 ],[ 24, 19, 13, 9 ],[ 25, 20, 15, 10 ],[ 26, 21, 16, 11 ],[ 18, 13, 8, 3 ],[ 19, 14, 9, 4 ],[ 20, 15, 10, 5 ],[ 13, 20, 27, 34 ]];

// Create efficient data structure for counting the selections
const numberToCounters = Array.from({length: 42}, () => []);
arrayOfArrays.map((arr) => ({ arr, selected: 0 }))
    .forEach(counter => counter.arr.forEach(k => 
        numberToCounters[k].push(counter))
    );

// Function to process a selection and see if 4 of the same array
const select = num => 
    numberToCounters[num].find(counter => ++counter.selected == counter.arr.length);

// I/O handling
for (let k = 0; k <= 41; k++) {
    let button = document.createElement("button");
    button.textContent = k;
    button.className = "choice";
    document.body.append(button);
}

document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    const button = e.target;
    if (button.className !== "choice") return;
    button.disabled = true;
    const counter = select(button.textContent);
    if (counter) { // game over
        for (let button of document.querySelectorAll(".choice")) button.disabled = true;
        document.querySelector("#output").textContent = "Matched all values in " + counter.arr;
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach in this snippet is to filter `arrayOfArrays` using the input array values. If the filtered result has arrays of length 4, four numbers from the input array match one of the arrays of `arrayOfArrays`.

```js
const arrayFromInput = [23,55,22,0,7,13,7,22,16,13,21,14];
const otherArrayFromInput = [23,55,22,1,14,15,98,6,7];
const log = str => document.querySelector("#result").textContent += `${str}\n`;
const arrayOfArrays = [
    [ 0, 7, 14, 21 ],
    [ 1, 8, 15, 22 ],
    [ 2, 9, 16, 23 ],
    [ 6, 13, 20, 27 ],
    // [...]
];

checkArrayExistence(arrayFromInput);
checkArrayExistence(otherArrayFromInput);

function checkArrayExistence(inputValues) {
  let report = `Check: any 4 of [${inputValues}] in one of arrayOfArrays?`;
  
  // from a HTML input field the values may be strings, so convert first
  intermediateArray = inputValues.map(Number);
  
  // for every array of arrayOfArrays, filter for every value of [input]
  const checked = arrayOfArrays
    .reduce( (reduced, current) => 
        reduced.concat([current.filter(v => intermediateArray.includes(v))]), [] )
    .filter(v => v.length === 4);
  
  log(`${report} ${checked.length ? "YEP" : "NOPE"}`);
  
  if (checked.length) {
    log(`  => Matching arrays in arrayOfArrays: ${JSON.stringify(checked)}`);
  }
};
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
 var arrayOfArrays = [
        [ 0, 7, 14, 21 ],
        [ 1, 8, 15, 22 ],
        [ 2, 9, 16, 23 ],
        [ 6, 13, 20, 27 ],

        [ 7, 14, 21, 28 ],
        [ 8, 15, 22, 29 ],
        [ 12, 19, 26, 33 ],
        [ 14, 21, 28, 35 ],

        [ 18, 25, 32, 39 ],
        [ 19, 26, 33, 40 ],
        [ 20, 27, 34, 41 ],
        [ 36, 31, 26, 21 ],

        [ 37, 32, 27, 22 ],
        [ 38, 33, 28, 23 ],
        [ 30, 25, 20, 15 ],
        [ 31, 26, 21, 16 ],

        [ 32, 27, 22, 17 ],
        [ 24, 19, 13, 9 ],
        [ 25, 20, 15, 10 ],
        [ 26, 21, 16, 11 ],

        [ 18, 13, 8, 3 ],
        [ 19, 14, 9, 4 ],
        [ 20, 15, 10, 5 ],
        [ 13, 20, 27, 34 ]
    ];
    newArrays = [];
    var noMatch = false;
    var addedNumbers = [];
    function addNumber() {
      if(noMatch || addedNumbers.length === 4) {
        return;
      }
      let value = document.querySelector('input').value;
      if(value) {
        addedNumbers.push(value);
        document.querySelector('span').textContent = [...addedNumbers];
        value = parseInt(value);
        if(newArrays.length == 0) {
          newArrays =  arrayOfArrays.filter(array => {
          return array.some(item => item == value);
          });
        } else {
          newArrays =  newArrays.filter(array => {
          return array.some(item => item == value);
          });
        }
        document.querySelector('input').value = '';
        if(addedNumbers.length === 4 && newArrays.length > 0) {
          alert('match found');
        }
        if(newArrays.length === 0) {
          noMatch = true;
          alert('No match found');
        }
        console.log(newArrays);
      }
    }
```

```html
<input type="number">
  <button onclick="addNumber()">Add Numbers</button>
  <span></span>
```